# A non-compact topological space with a complete metric, and (another) totally bounded metric

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is compact iff there exists a complete and totally bounded metric (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space)).

Do you know an example of a non-compact metrizable topological space for which we have a metric that is complete, but then not totally bounded, and a metric that is not complete, but totally bounded?

Comment: Take $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric for the first example, and $(0,1)$ with the usual metric for the second. You can assume they are the same space since they are bijective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric for the first example, and $(0,1)$ with the usual metric for the second. You can assume they are the same space since they are bijective.